# Using getters in another method won't work?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, symbols, getter

I am trying to create a program that creates a deck of 52 cards. When I try to compile the code, it keeps saying "cannot find symbol on all of the getName getters in the createDeck method. I'm new to Java programming so I'm at a loss as to what to do. Any suggestions would be helpful. Here's the code:

```
public class Card {


private int value;
 private String name;
 private String suit;

 public void setValue(int v){
  value = v;
 }
 public int getValue(){
  return value;
 }

 public void setName(String n){
  name = n;
 }
 public String getName(){
  return name;
 }

 public void setSuit(String s){
  suit = s;
 }
 public String getSuit(){
  return suit;
 }

}
```

This class should create a deck:

```
public class cardDeck {
 int[] values = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
 String[] names = {"Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "King", "Queen", "Jack", "Ace",};
 String[] suits = {"Clubs", "Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds"};

 public Card[] createDeck (Card[] d){
 for(int j:deck){
  d[j] = new Card();
  for(String k:names){
   d[j].setName(k);
 }
  for(int i:values){
   if((d[j].getName == ("King")) || (d[j].getName == ("Queen")) || (d[j].getName == ("Jack"))){
      d[j].setValue(10);
    }else if(d[j].getName == ("Ace")){
      d[j].setValue(11);
    }else{
  d[j].setValue(i);
    }
  }
  for(String l:suits){
   d[j].setSuit(l);
  }
 }
 return d;
} 
}
```

Here's the tester class:

```
 class CardTest {
 public static void main(String[] args){
  Card[] deck = new Card[52];
  cardDeck playingCards = new cardDeck();
  playingCards.createDeck(deck);

  for(int q = 0; q < 52; q++){
   System.out.println(deck[q]);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Don't compare `String` ( or  generally any kind of `Object` ) using `==`. Since it's an Object, you should use the `equals` method from `String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing parentheses for the method call:

```
if((d[j].getName() == ("King")) ...
```

Some languages (such as ActionScript) support adding getters that look like properties, instead of methods.  In Java, there is no such special syntax for getters and setters, they are simply normal methods, and all methods must be accessed only with standard method call syntax — `()` — even if it has no parameters.

Comment: I made the changes and it compiled. I also changed the test class output to:
    System.out.println("A "+deck[q].getName()+" of "+deck[q].getSuit())
However, it only prints out "A Ace of Diamonds". Do yo have any idea why it just makes an ace of diamonds? Before I changed the output, it printed "Card@132jg1 Card@424324..." and so on. If all the cards have different bits, shouldn't they each print something different?

Comment: It doesn't look like the code would compile still.  What is the reference to `deck` in `for(int j:deck)`?  Values of integer arrays initialize to 0, so maybe that's your problem; you need to use the index instead of the value.

Comment: I fixed that as well.  I changed it to a conventional for loop and made it j <52, so it compiles. It still prints out the same values for each card. I need to move each element to the end of the array after it's used but I don't know how to do that.